# Python hdfs3 fails to list non-owned files

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to list files from a HDFS directory using hdfs3 library:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
>>> from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
>>> hdfs = HDFileSystem(host='abc.com', port=8020)
>>> hdfs.ls('/user/user123')
[{'group': 'group321', 'name': '/user/user123/.Trash' ... }]
>>> hdfs.ls('/user')
[]
```

I am running python as a user123. The directory /user/user123 is owned by user123. The directory /user is owned by another user, but everybody can read it:

```
[user123@hostname ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 12 items
drwxr-xr-x   - admin     admin            0 2016-10-21 09:39 /user
...
```

Unfortunately in this case hdfs3 library reads/lists only HDFS files/directories of the owner and nothing else.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, it is a bug in the package. I found useful to use another package: hdfs. It can be installed with:

```
pip install hdfs
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-hdfs
```